# logging into sql

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I am a student learning sql and working an assignment to set up a database in mySQL 5.5 community version. The command I am given does not work as detailed. Here is what I have done so far:
This is the command that I am told to use after setting up mySQL 5.5.

```
mysql –h localhost –u root -p
```

This brings back a long screen of help commands. I found out that instead I need to use:
`mysql -u root -p`. Then I get my password prompt that works. That starts sql. Next I was given these statements to create a user named user1.

```
USE mysql;
create user ‘user1’@’localhost’ identified by ‘user1’;
grant select, insert, update, delete, create, drop, references, execute on *.* to ‘user1’@’localhost’;
exit
```

I entered these line by line and they seem to work. No errors are returned. However when I try to start the user with the following commands:

```
Login as user1
mysql –h localhost –u user1 –p
password is user1
```

I get a long list of help commands when i exexute the mysql line.

What is incorrect with the commands I have executed and also why? I initially think it may be that these commands were written for an earlier version? I was initially told to reinstall mysql and did that with no errors. I get the same results as before reinstalling it. If I need to explain or add screenshots, I will be glad to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html

```
mysql -h localhost -u user1 -ppassword database_name_here
```

Your other option:

```
mysql -h localhost -u user1 -p database_name_here
```

But for the second one you will have to type the password.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not answering you question specifically, but I recommend you to get an interface to mySQL which makes it all a bit easier. In my case I still use the terminal to perform some queries once in a while, but for user management and to get a better presentation I use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) which makes the whole process much more neat. Good luck!

Comment: That sounds good, but not part of my class yet. I will look into that. Like when I started out learning hand coding html, did not care for it.... Now I can think of not using Dreamweaver. :)